# How to open an .exe application which is hosted on different server using html?

Tags: javascript, html, exe, hta

How to open an .exe application which is hosted on different server using html ?

```
var w = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

w.Exec("C:\Program Files\Adobe\Photoshp.exe");
```

I tried the above code but it's working with local .exe bt nothing is working with external .exe

Comment: Are you trying to open a .exe, from the local machine, that lives on the server? Using JavaScript?

Comment: Can't be done... serious security issues. You might use asp.net or some other server side programming to open a .exe that will run on the server... but technically that would not be using JavaScript to do it

Comment: By using front end , can't we open it ? or may be we first download it with a single link on the page and den it ask automatically to run ?

Comment: downloading it is easy. but running it on a single click would require bypassing browser security checks... more clicks. To run it on the server could be done with a single href click that calls a .aspx page that fires the .exe on the server. But JavaScript, by itsefl, can only "play" inside the browser

Comment: Come on guys, this is tagged as **HTA**.

Comment: yeah its basically a hta page which has a link that should run external link

Comment: [humbly bows his head in disgrace and walks out quietly]...... D'oh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is an intranet stuff, try this:

```
w.Exec("\\\\Your_server_name\\C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Photoshop.exe");
```

or:

```
w.Run("\\\\Your_server_name\\C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Photoshop.exe");
```

`Your_server_name` can also be an IP address. Notice also doubled backslashes, and the fact, that the path *must* be absolute, you can't use any drive letters mapped in local workstation. Notice also, that usually server name is not the root of the server (like C:), rather it's pointing to a folder in the server.

Both examples work great for me, no matter, if the HTA is saved in the server or workstation. Only I could imagine why they wouldn't work (additional to a wrong path), is a case, when you have not rights to the referred folder. Or... you're trying to run exe from an external WEB server, which afaik is not possible.

Comment: @Anuj What it says in the error message? Are you using a correct path to photoshop.exe? Notice you've a typo in your post (Photoshp.exe).

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do that using JS on client side directly as this will be a security issue. The best way to do this will be first download the exe file, via http and then run it. Once you try to do this user will also be prompted for it.

Comment: bt there are many applications which actually run the .exe app without actually downloading it

Comment: As far as I know they download it in temporary location and then run it.